# What is wrong with "I admired the patience she spoke with"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

> I admired the patience she spoke with.

This sentence comes from the preposition section of *Practical English Usage* (Swan 2016).

I think the sentence was to express:

> She spoke with patience. I admired her patience.

I tried to rearrange it:

> I admired the patience with which she spoke.

This is a formal structure according to the book. But I could not figure out what is wrong with the original sentence. Is there any other way to say it in a more conversational tone?

Comment: Would _I admired her for the patience she spoke with._ help you?

Comment: Why do you think there is something wrong with the original sentence?

Comment: If you want more conversational, I'd suggest: "She spoke with patience; I admired that."  or "She spoke with patience, and I admired that."  Or just end a sentence with a preposition, if it feels unnatural to do anything else.  To paraphrase: "That is a rule up with which I will not put."

Answer (score 2):

All of your comments are correct. In practice, we try not to end a sentence with a preposition, although there is increasing tolerance to that, especially in spoken English.

The last example you show is more correct but very formal and it would be unusual to hear it in spoken American English. What about:

> She spoke with patience that I admired.